# Suppose $T \in \mathscr{L}(W)$ has no eigenvalues and $T^4 = I$. Prove that $T^2 = -I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T \in \mathscr{L}(W)$ has no eigenvalues and $T^4 = I$. Prove that $T^2 = -I$.

I intend to solve this math in the following way:

Let's do the math in the opposite direction,
say $T^2=-I$. Now $T^4 = (T^2)(T^2)=(-I)(-I)=I$.

Is it okay? am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: This is indeed a faulty argument—you're proving the converse of what you're asked to prove. (Another red flag is that you never use the hypothesis that $T$ has no eigenvalues.) The same fallacy can be seen with real numbers: suppose you're asked to prove the (suspicious) statement "if $x^4=1$ then $x^2=-1$". You can just as easily say "let's do it in the opposite direction, say $x^2=-1$, then $x^4=x^2x^2=(-1)(-1)=1$". Does that feel like a proof of "if $x^4=1$ then $x^2=-1$"?

Comment: Would you please enlighten me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As I usually tell my students, if you are not using one of the hypotheses, your argument is immediately suspect. Here you are not using that $T$ has no eigenvalues; if for instance you take $T=I$, then $T^2=T^4=I$.

Let $V=T^2$. So $V^2=I$. As $V$ commutes with $I$, we get
$$
0=V^2-I=(V+I)(V-I)=(V-I)(V+I).
$$
If $V+I\ne0$, choose $v$ with $w=(V+I)v\ne0$. Then $(V-I)w=0$. That is $$(T-I)(T+I)w=0.$$ If $z=(T+I)w\ne0$, then $Tz=z$, a contradiction. And if $z=0$, then $Tw=-w$, a contradiction. So the only possibility is that $V+I=0$.